# Find the names of files found by the find command in another location

Tags: linux, sh

I want to be able to find the names of files in one directory /foo and search for them in another directory /bar. I have this:

```
 find "../foo" -type f \
     -execdir find "../bar" -name {} \;
```

but it is not working because the entire file path is getting passed in by the -execdir. -execdir documentation states that it should be passing only the base filename so its curious that it is still passing the whole file name. I get this error:

find: warning: Unix filenames usually don't contain slashes (though pathnames do).  That means that '-name '[full path of found file]''

so it is trying to insert the whole file path. I have tried piping the output of find into find using xargs as well but not having any luck

Comment: Can you add sample input with `tree` command output before and after? (expected output). This will be more clear for all

Answer (score 1):

`-execdir` is not what You defined. it changes your directory to the sub directory containing the matched file and run your command.

you can do something like:

```
find "../foo" -type f -exec basename "{}" \; \
  | xargs -I% -n1 find "../bar" -type f -name "%"
```

but its not efficient in most cases since You should run the find command multiple times.

I'd rather do something else like:

- first find the files I want:
  `find "../foo" -type f -exec basename "{}" \;`
- then add a '$' to the end of file names:
  `sed 's/$/\$/'`
- then run the find command in second directory and pass to to grep as a fd and use generated filenames from `sed`
  `egrep  -f -  <( find "../bar" -type f )`

all together

```
find "../foo" -type f -exec basename "{}" \; \
  | sed 's/$/\$/' \
  | egrep  -f -  <( find "../bar" -type f )
```

I'm still not sure if its the best way to do it.